# How to rebuild the filesystem of a recovered partition

Tags: linux, data-recovery, dd, fsck

I managed to ruin a server drive by trying to clone it to another drive with `dd`. In the process, the original `boot` and `sda1` partitions were overwritten.

I immediatly stopped using the drive,I made an image of the damaged drive with `ddrescue` then attempted to recover the lost partition with `testdisk`. Running a deepscan I found what seemed to resemble my lost `sda1` partition so I restored.

After running an `fsck` on it and `sudo e2fsck -b block_number /dev/xxx` to restore a uncorrupted superblock, I was able to mount the partition and found a `lost+found` directory containing almost all my files.

It seems my files are there so how would I be able to recover/rebuild the filesystem of the original partition?